# Asynchronous SELECT from sqlite DB with QT?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to use an asynchronous method to select strings from SQLite DB with QT; how can I accomplish that?

Please explain to me with code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Asynchronous Database Access with Qt 4.x](http://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~courses/coe518/LinuxJournal/elj2007-158-asynQt.pdf), help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To allow sqlite to behave asynchronously, you'd have to use their [asynchronous module](http://www.sqlite.org/asyncvfs.html).  I have no experience with it, though.

I would recommend using sqlite without it though and letting Qt handle all the asynchronous behavior.  You would have to do that to keep a GUI responsive anyway, which is what I presume is  your intent.